# Turn off Voice call on my Plivo number

Tags: sms-gateway, plivo

I want to turn off the Voice Calls feature on my Plivo number because I only use them for sending SMS through their API. Sometimes when people receive a sms , they call back to the number they see and wait on hold or something for about 45 seconds incurring in unnecessary costs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to achieve this by removing answer url for the application.

- go to https://manage.plivo.com/number/
- in the last column you should be able to see `Application`
- click on the application against your number
- now your should be on page like: `https://manage.plivo.com/app/edit/[application-id]/`
- remove value mentioned under `Answer URL`

This should setup no answering url for your number and hence people cannot call you on this number anymore.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I also found another way of doing this , and is creating an xml file with the following <Response>
    <Hangup reason="rejected" />
</Response>, this will tell plivo to reject all incoming calls.